# Loop through a system argument in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, while-loop

This is a blackjack program. When stand function is false, main function is not supposed to append getCard() to myCards but for some reason it still does and it counts backwards. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import random
import sys

def get_card():
return random.randint(1, 13)

def score(cards):
soft_ace_count = 0
total = 0
Ace = False
```

## To check if an Ace exists in hand and to set face cards to correct value

```
for card in cards:
    if card == 1:
        Ace = True
        total+=11
        soft_ace_count+=1
    elif card == 11 or card == 12 or card == 13:
        total+=10
    else:
        total+=card
```

## To convert Ace

```
for x in cards:
    if Ace and total > 21:
        total-=10
        soft_ace_count-=1

return (total, soft_ace_count)

def stand(stand_on_value, stand_on_soft, cards):
total, soft_ace_count = score(cards)
print(f"In stand: {total}")

if total > 17 and total < 22:
    return True

if total == stand_on_value:
    return True

elif soft_ace_count == 0 and total == 17:
    return True

elif stand_on_soft == True and total == 17:
    return True
else:
    return False

def numBusts(s):
    total, soft_ace_count = s
    busted_count = 0
    if total > 21:
        busted_count+=1
    return busted_count

def main():
    numSims = int(sys.argv[1])-1
    standVal = int(sys.argv[2])
    strategy = sys.argv[3]
    strategy.upper()

    for sims in range(numSims+1):
        percent_bust = 0.0
        myCards = [get_card(), get_card()]

        print(f"in main: first two cards: {myCards}")

        stand(standVal, strategy, myCards)

        while not stand(standVal, strategy, myCards):

            myCards.append(get_card())

    percent_bust = (numBusts(score(myCards))/(numSims+1)) * 100
    print(f"in main: percent bust: {percent_bust}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    [The image shows how it runs correctly until the while not stand function returns False.][1]main()
```

I have tried running for loops, not running loops, and other things.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`while not stand` will append to the result of get_card() to myCards when stand is False.

But in your question, you say you don't want it to append when stand() is False.

Also, you seem to be calling the stand function twice consecutively, is this intended? The conditional actually calls the function in order to check its result.

Perhaps this will do what you expect?:

```
for sims in range(numSims+1):
    percent_bust = 0.0
    myCards = [get_card(), get_card()]

    print(f"in main: first two cards: {myCards}")

    if stand(standVal, strategy, myCards) is True:
        myCards.append(get_card())
```

This conditional will append to myCards if and only if `stand()` returns True, but **not** when it returns False, 0, or None.